# How to enable transcluency in Kvantum with fractional scaling?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5, hdpi, effects

I started using fractional scaling after switching to a HiDPI screen, and noticed that the transcluency in Dolphin, Gwenview are gone. I am using Kvantum.

How to enable transcluency with fractional scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [comment](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/issues/445#issuecomment-742104606) on GitHub, where the author of Kvantum says it is deliberately disabled to prevent artifacts in some places.

Follow these steps to enable it.

`Kvantum Manager → Hacks → Disable translucency with non-integer scaling` (uncheck it).

I could not notice any glitch in Plasma 5.19.5 after enabling translucency.

Comment: I decided to post this on Ask Ubuntu because that particular comment on GitHub took quite some time to find.